# Proper way to extract first elment inside multiple nested list

Tags: c#

I'm getting data from soap service and want to know the proper way to extract first element inside nested list

example of the problem i'm having

```
 tempModel.Value = req.Data
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Readings
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Extract
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Values
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Reading;
```

The thing is the service is returning the lists of elements and i need to extract the first element inside each of the multiple nested layers.

This code here will give me **exception** if *any* of the list is `null`.

I know i can do try and catch but i have five of these elements that i want to populate the viewmodel. I'm trying to search for clean solution of this problem because i understand how i can do it the "ugly way".

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not propagate `null` with `?.`? `tempModel.Value = req.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.Readings?.FirstOrDefault()?.Extract?.FirstOrDefault()?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.Reading;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest *null propagation* with a help of `?.` (instead of `.`)

```
       tempModel.Value = req.Data
          .FirstOrDefault()
         ?.Readings
         ?.FirstOrDefault()
         ?.Extract
         ?.FirstOrDefault()
         ?.Values
         ?.FirstOrDefault()
         ?.Reading;
```

whenever `null` appears it will be *propagated* to the end (and you'll get `null` as a final result) while no exception will be thrown.